# How to pass optional account in Anchor Context?

Tags: anchor

I have an instruction that either sends SOL or SPL tokens to the signer depending upon the option chosen. I only want to include a mint of the SPL token in the context of SPL token option being chosen. Is it possible to use an optional account in the context or is it only possible through remaining_accounts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like Anchor 0.26 added support for optional accounts, might be useful for your use case

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0260---2022-12-15

> lang: Add support for optionally passing in accounts using the syntax
> Optional<Account<'info, T>>. Shouldn't affect existing programs but
> may be a breaking change to tools that use the anchor generated IDL.

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/2101

Comment: Very helpful, upvoted :). Small correction though: The correct syntax is `Option` not `Optional`